# Equation driven conical spring not rebuilding properly in Solidworks 2019

Tags: solidworks

I'm trying to make an equation driven conical spiral, you can download the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/14u0kdhxeui9px8/Coil%20spring%20no%20disk.SLDPRT?dl=0). I know that I can use the spiral tool to achieve this but there are reasons why I want to do it like this. I have five global variables that control the characteristics of the spring: the initial radius ri, the final radius rf, height H, number of coils nc, and diameter of wire d (it's a square wire so the diameter is the width/height of the square). The equations for generating the coil are:

```
x=("ri"-t*(("rf"-"ri")/"H"))*cos(t*((2*pi*"nc")/"H"))

y=("ri"-t*(("rf"-"ri")/"H"))*sin(t*((2*pi*"nc")/"H"))

z=t
```

with limits from t=0 to t=H. The problem is that when I change the variables, the spring does not rebuild, even when I use Ctrl+Q several times. I have no idea why this is. I have another small coil above the spring which I'm going to use to make an end coil and it seems to update ok but the main coil doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn’t global variables work with the standard helix method?

Comment: Hi @enea19 - I downloaded your file, edited some of the global variables, and it seemed to rebuild just fine? It has to be Ctrl+Q rather than Ctrl+B, but I can't replicate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer your original question re: why using CTRL+Q did not successfully rebuild for you when using an equation driven curve - because when I downloaded your file, I could not recreate the error.

What I can do is demonstrate how you could apply your global variables to the built-in helix/spiral tool, such that the you can edit your variables in exactly the same way, and it automatically rebuilds whenever you edit a global variable value. (SW sends a CTRL+B when you press enter in the value/equation box).

[image: Editing Global Variables on Coil Spring]

I'm not just suggesting this 'just because I can' - it's a more robust way to model this object. Your supplied model using the equation curve takes almost **four times** as long to rebuild. (I have deleted features in your model after the initial sweep to keep it a level playing field)

[image: Rebuild times for helix/spiral vs equation curve]

EDIT: Here is my file to download if you would like: http://www.filedropper.com/conicalspringglobalvariablesdemo

Comment: FYI - I'm running SW2019 SP4.0