# Solidworks - parametric conical helix antenna on a dielectric

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm stuck half way through construction of parametric conical helix antenna on a dieletric. I have created the intersection line but I'm struggling to make it a planar surface on top of the conical object as shown in the picture attached. I also have attached the Solidworks file.

[image]

Comment: where is the attached .SLDPRT file?

Comment: Can you confirm if this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIAcr.png is the shape you're trying to make?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, yes, that's the shape I'm trying to make. I tried to attach ".SLDPRT" file but this forum not allowing me. Any other way to pass the file? Can I send you via email?

Comment: You can use e.g. we transfer, or filedropper, and paste a link to the file here. But now I know that’s the shape you’re after, I can post a tutorial tomorrow when I am back at my computer. (On mobile now!)

Comment: please post tutorial on solidworks. here you go. i uploaded the file into file dropper. http://www.filedropper.com/conicalhelix3

Comment: I want to do a parametric antenna or with equation. The cone was easy to parameterize, but I'm not sure about the helix. please help in that too.

Comment: I’ve actually already posted an answer on that here - https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32340/equation-driven-conical-spring-not-rebuilding-properly-in-solidworks-2019

Comment: Please can you confirm how you would like to define your parameters? Height, Max and Min Diameter? Base diameter and Cone Angle?

Comment: hi Jonathan, you can define as you like. i can edit it later. no issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See below for how I set up my Global Variables, and for all equations that I used. The only formulae that actually needed calculations are the taper angle for the helix (calculated using basic trigonometry from the Min/Max diameters of the cone, and the height) and the height of the helix (the height of the final object, plus 2x the pitch. This allows it to be cut to height and have a smooth runout - I hope this is correct.

[image: Equation Editor View]

The steps that you need to take to model this item are as follows:

1. Set up your global variables *before* you start modelling.
2. I renamed 'Top Plane' as 'Base Plane', since this will be the base of the cone. I then inserted a plane called "Max Height", set to an offset from the Base Plane, defined by the global variable "Height". Always define your planes or axes as early in the history tree as possible.
3. Set up your sketch for the cone. I started with an infinite length centreline - this allows us to use diameter dimensions, rather than needing to divide the global variables by 2. The cone is defined by two horizontal construction lines, one coincident with the origin (and base plane), and the other with the 'Max Height' plane. Note that the "Height" is not dimensioned here, it's driven by the location of the plane. I have added an extension past the Base and Max Height planes equal to the "Pitch" global variable.

   [image: cone sketch]
4. Revolve the Cone - It should automatically select the infinite centreline as the axis of rotation.
5. Generate your Helix. I started a sketch on the base face of the cone, and used convert entities to make a circle coincident with the bottom edge. You can't type equations directly into the helix tool (like you can with regular dimensions), so you need to just type a starting point, before moving to the Equation editor to add values as shown in my first image. I set it to be defined by Pitch and Height, with taper enabled. I put my Cone profile on the right plane so that a start angle of 0 deg will be coincident with the Cone Profile Sketch. You can see in the image below how to select the helix definition - if height and revolution is more appropriate, you can select it here, and adjust your global variables as required.

[image: how to select helix defintion]

6. Set up your Antenna profile sketch. This should be coincident with the Cone profile, and the start of the Helix. I have set the width and thickness equal to their respective global variables. Note how the angle of this is defined by the Cone Profile sketch, which is in turn driven by the Max/Min diameters.

[image: antenna profile]

7. Sweep the Antenna along the Helix. Uncheck 'Merge result' in the options to keep this as a separate body from the cone.
8. Cut off the bottom of both parts - using Cut with Surface and the Base Plane
9. Cut off the top of both parts - using Cut with Surface and the Max Height Plane
10. Sit back and admire your handiwork

[image: parametric helix antenna]

Comment: the .SLDPRT is available at: http://www.filedropper.com/coilhelixantennae

Comment: Thank you so much, Jonathan. I have one more question. Is it possible to parameterize the number of turns for helix? That is the most critical parameter when optimizing.

Comment: Yes, easy - just define your helix by number of turns and height instead of pitch. This is why I asked you what your key variables were!!

Comment: All is well. One last question. 1) I didn't see how we can define number of turn in a helix from Solidworks. I tried in helix options, but it didn't appear to me. Please explain where I can get them. Thank you so much for a detailed explanation. It was beneficial. How can I rate your help so you can get credit for that? I'm, new here that why asking.

Comment: I’ll edit my answer to show how to define by turns later this evening when I can get to my laptop.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already did the current design myself. Without your help, certainly not possible.

Comment: You could just make a new global variable for number of turns and then set the formula for the pitch global variable to “Height/(Number of turns+2)” ?

Comment: yes, i can certainly do that myself. thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105073/discussion-between-pragash-sangaran-and-jonathan-r-swift).